# Proof: Does every spanning list have to contain a linearly independent list of the greatest possible length?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say that every list of vectors that is linearly independent in V has length <= n. Does there exist a list of vectors that spans V while only a linearly independent list of length less than n can be found inside of this list?

For example:

Say we use R3 for V, can the list:
((1,0,0), (0,1,1), and some additional vectors so that this spans R3 )
have only the list (1,0,0),(0,1,1) in it that is linearly independent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the $\leq n$ sharp? As written it seems like you can have $n$ be larger than the dimension.

Comment: In this case n would be the dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a list cannot exist. In other words, if a list (or set) $S$ of vectors  spans an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, then there must exist a list of $n$ vectors that spans $V$.

Suppose that a list $S \subset V$ of length $m$ is such that the maximal length among its linearly independent sublists is $k$, with $k<n$. Without loss of generality (i.e. using a suitable reordering of the list), suppose that the first elements of $S$, $v_1,\dots,v_k,$ are linearly independent. For $j = (k+1),\dots,m$, the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_j\}$ must fail to be linearly independent. Using this, we conclude that $v_j$ can be written in the form $v_j = c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_k v_k$ for some scalars $c_1,\dots,c_k$.

That is, every vector of $S$ is an element of the set $\operatorname{span}(\{v_1,\dots, v_k\})$, which is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$. It follows that the span of $S$ is equal to $\operatorname{span}(\{v_1,\dots, v_k\})$, which means that the span of $S$ is $k$-dimensional, which means that the span of $S$ cannot be equal to $V$.